Unable to get reference to Vuetify form inside a v-stepper
I am able to get this to work using the basic example of a v-stepper. I can get the ref to the form, no problem. I need to do some extra work such as marking the step as completed so I have to use a v-stepper-header and a v-stepper-window. It seems as soon as I put the form inside a v-stepper-window-item I can no longer create a reference to my form. I get an error:  Uncaught TypeError: idForm.value?.validate is not a function
Why do I lose the ability to reference once the form is nested that deep?
    <template>
  <v-container max-width="600">
    <v-card class="mx-auto">
      <v-stepper v-model="currentStep" hide-actions>
        <v-stepper-header>
          <v-stepper-item
            v-for="(step, index) in steps"
            :key="index"
            :complete="completedSteps[index]"
            :title="step"
            :value="index + 1"
          />
        </v-stepper-header>

        <v-stepper-window>
          <v-stepper-window-item v-for="(step, index) in steps" :key="index" :value="index + 1">
            <v-card flat>
              <v-card-title v-if="index === 0">Driver Code and Social Security Number</v-card-title>
              <v-card-text v-if="index === 0">
                <div class="mb-6">
                  Please enter your driver code and the last 5 digits of your Social Security Number.
                </div>
                <v-form ref="idForm" @submit.prevent="submitIdentity">
                  <v-text-field
                    v-model="idFormData.driverCode"
                    label="Driver Code"
                    :rules="[rules, driverCodeRules].flat()"
                  />
                  <v-text-field
                    v-model="idFormData.ssnLast5"
                    label="Last 5 of your SSN"
                    :rules="[rules, ssnRules].flat()"
                  />
                  <div class="d-flex justify-end">
                    <v-btn
                      class="mt-6 pa-5 submit-btn d-flex align-center justify-center"
                      color="success"
                      :loading="loading"
                      type="submit"
                    >
                      Next
                    </v-btn>
                  </div>
                </v-form>
              </v-card-text>

              <v-card-title v-if="index === 1">Set New Password</v-card-title>
              <v-card-text v-if="index === 1">
                <div class="mb-6">Please enter a new password.</div>
                <v-form ref="passwordForm" @submit.prevent="submitPassword">
                  <v-text-field
                    v-model="passwordFormData.password"
                    label="New Password"
                    :rules="rules"
                    type="password"
                  />
                  <v-text-field
                    v-model="passwordFormData.repeatPassword"
                    label="Re-enter password"
                    :rules="rules"
                    type="password"
                  />
                  <v-btn
                    block
                    class="mt-6 pa-5"
                    color="success"
                    :loading="loading"
                    text="Next"
                    type="submit"
                  />
                </v-form>
              </v-card-text>

              <v-card-title v-if="index === 2">Email Confirmation</v-card-title>
              <v-card-text v-if="index === 2">
                <div class="mb-6">Please confirm your email address.</div>
                <v-text-field
                  v-model="emailFormData.email"
                  label="Email Address"
                  :rules="rules"
                />
                <v-btn
                  class="mt-6 pa-5"
                  color="success"
                  @click="confirmEmail"
                >
                  Confirm Email
                </v-btn>
              </v-card-text>

              <v-card-title v-if="index === 3">Complete Registration</v-card-title>
              <v-card-text v-if="index === 3">
                <div class="mb-6">Your registration is complete!</div>
                <v-btn
                  class="mt-6 pa-5"
                  color="success"
                  @click="finishRegistration"
                >
                  Finish
                </v-btn>
              </v-card-text>
            </v-card>
          </v-stepper-window-item>
        </v-stepper-window>
      </v-stepper>
    </v-card>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
  import { ref } from "vue";

  const currentStep = ref(1);
  const steps = ref([
    "Identity",
    "Password",
    "Email",
    "Complete",
  ]);

  // Form data

  const idForm = ref();
  const idFormData = ref({ driverCode: "", ssnLast5: "" });
  const passwordForm = ref();
  const passwordFormData = ref({ password: "", repeatPassword: "" });
  const emailFormData = ref({ email: "" }); // Added for email confirmation step
  const rules = [(v: any) => !!v || "This field is required"];
  const driverCodeRules = [(v: any) => v.length < 7 || "Incorrect driver code format"];
  const ssnRules = [(v: any) => v.length < 6 || "Only enter the last 5 of your SSN"];
  const loading = ref(false);
  const completedSteps = ref<boolean[]>([false, false, false, false]);

  const submitIdentity = () => {
    idForm.value?.validate().then((result: { valid: boolean }) => {
      if (result.valid) {
        completedSteps.value[currentStep.value - 1] = true;
        currentStep.value++;
      }
    });
  };

  const submitPassword = () => {
    passwordForm.value?.validate().then((result: { valid: boolean }) => {
      if (result.valid) {
        completedSteps.value[currentStep.value - 1] = true;
        currentStep.value++;
      }
    });
  };

  // Placeholder functions for email confirmation and finish steps
  const confirmEmail = () => {
    completedSteps.value[currentStep.value - 1] = true;
    currentStep.value++;
  };

  const finishRegistration = () => {
    // Logic for finishing registration
    console.log("Registration completed!");
  };
</script>


Vue puts the ref into an array, this usually happens when the elements are created in a v-for (see documentation). Not sure why it happens here, maybe from the v-stepper-window-items? Anyway, using idForm[0]?.validate() works when I try it out.
